# Keeping Pushbullet for Chrome active with Chrome closed?

Tags: chrome, elementary-os

I'm using Elementary OS Luna (an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative) on an Acer C720 Chromebook with Firefox as my browser of choice. I'm a big fan of Pushbullet to mirror my Android notifications from my phone to my desktop and have found it to be my preferred method of doing so on Linux thus far, but the Chrome plugin is far superior to the Firefox one, IMO.

At the present moment, I am running Chrome minimized at boot via Devilspie in order to get the Chrome Pushbullet plugin to actually run in the background, but this is an obviously ugly way of accomplishing this, as Chrome is eating RAM without actually being used for anything else.

I am looking for a way to either:

A) Get Pushbullet to actively run in the background and mirror notifications with Chrome closed, which I was under the impression was possible

B) Run Chrome with the absolute minimum of resource consumption and/or processes, seeing as I am using it solely to power the Pushbullet extension

Is there a way to do A? Is there a preferred method or set of flags/options I can use to accomplish B?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a third party Pushbullet Indicator available. Now this guide is for Ubuntu 14.04 and has a warning about not working under 13.10. "The Ubuntu 13.10 package has a dependency that's not available for Ubuntu 13.10 and thus, is not usable" I have no idea if it will work in 12.04 but it might be worth trying! http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/pushbullet-indicator-send-files-links.html

EDIT: The author of the post has commented saying that a user was able to get it working under 12.04. http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/pushbullet-indicator-send-files-links.html#comment-1374036505